# docker php gettext not translating

Tags: php, docker, utf-8, gettext

I'm desperate finding a solution why gettext is not translating. I followed multiple tutorials and have no clue why it is not working. Locales are installed, gettext too, activated, loaded in php.ini and still not working. Currently I'm trying to translate from english to czech.

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ locales gettext

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gettext \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    intl \
    gettext
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    sed -i -e 's/# cs_CZ.UTF-8 UTF-8/cs_CZ.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8 
ENV LANGUAGE cs_CZ:en_US:en
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-enable intl gettext
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN apache2ctl restart
EXPOSE 80
```

Languages should be installed corrently

```
$ locale -a
C
cs_CZ.utf8
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

File structure

```
index.php
│
locale   
│
└───cs_CZ.utf8
│   │
│   └───LC_MESSAGES
│       │   messages.mo
│       │   messages.po
│   
└───en_US.utf8
│   │
│   └───LC_MESSAGES
│       │   messages.mo
│       │   messages.po
```

messages.po in cs translation

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-10-05 10:15+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: cs_CZ.utf8\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"

#: index.php:42
msgid "HELLO_WORLD"
msgstr "Ahoj světe"

#: index.php:43
msgid "TEST_TRANSLATION"
msgstr "Testovací překlad"
```

messages.po is generated via msgfmt

index.php

```
$locale = 'cs_CZ.utf8';
$domain = 'messages';
setlocale(LC_TIME, "");
$results = putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
if (!$results) {
    exit('putenv failed');
}

$results = setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
if (!$results) {
    exit('setlocale failed: locale function is not available on this platform, or the given local does not exist in this environment');
}

$results = bindtextdomain($domain, "locale/$locale");
echo 'new text domain is set: ' . $results . "\n";

$results = textdomain($domain);
echo 'current message domain is set: ' . $results . "<br>";

echo _("HELLO_WORLD");
echo "<br>";
echo _("TEST_TRANSLATION");
```

It returns

```
new text domain is set: /var/www/html/locale/cs_CZ.utf8 current message domain is set: messages
HELLO_WORLD
TEST_TRANSLATION
```

Is there any other way how to debug gettext? Am I missing something? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the culprit was LANGUAGE, as debian looks up this variable first, even before LC_ALL!

```
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");
```